# How to get DATABASE_CONFIG value inside a plugin in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I want to access the DATABASE_CONFIG class values located at `app/config/database.php` inside a plugin `app/Plugin/Myplugin/bootstrap.php`

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {
    public $redis = array(
        'datasource' => 'Redis.RedisSource',
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '6379',
        'db' => '2'
    );
}
```

I want to access the `$redis` host and port inside `Myplugin`

EDIT: THE CAKEPHP VERSION IS 2.1.2

Comment: which version you are using of cakephp ?

Comment: I am using cakephp version 2.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the database details :-

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
$dataSource = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('redis');
$host = $dataSource->config['host'];
$port = $dataSource->config['port'];
```